# 500 Error when hitting route /api/profile/twitter for IBM Watson Personality Insights application

Tags: ibm-watson, personality-insights

I have forked and cloned this repo: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-nodejs

I've added my Consumer Key & Secret in the `credentials.json` file like it states in the `README` but I'm getting a `500 Error`.  I think the issue is that I need to include my Access Token & Access Token Secret, but it's unclear where I would include that.

Here is the `500 Error` I get (Note: I replaced the sensitive paths and variables) :

```
GET /auth/twitter? 302 227.700 ms - 0
error: Error: Failed to find request token in session
    at SessionStore.get (/project/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/requesttoken/session.js:13:44)
    at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate (/project/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:214:33)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/project/node_modules/passport-twitter/lib/strategy.js:87:40)
    at attempt (/project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
    at authenticate (/project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13) 'url:' '/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=SOME_TOKEN&oauth_verifier=SOME_VERIFIER' 'Error:' code=500, code=undefined, error=undefined
GET /auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=SOME_TOKEN&oauth_verifier=SOME_VERIFIER 500 6.464 ms - 23
```

I also get a `401 Error` when I am trying to access others' tweets ***without*** Oauth, specifically I get this error:

```
error: { code: 401,
error: 'Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials' }     'url:' '/api/profile/twitter' 
'Error:' code=401, code=401, error=There was a problem processing the personality. Please check your credentials.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are getting the 401 on the Twitter call? The instructions for setting up the Twitter access are in the instructions to the repo at the link you provide, under the heading 'Setting Up Twitter Application'.

Comment: Hi chughts, thanks for the reply.  I checked again, and it seems that I'm getting a 500 error when actually trying to sign into Twitter and get/post my tweets & I'm getting a 401 error when I'm reading other's tweets (without signing in myself).  I read the instructions in the README, but am still experiencing this issue.

Comment: If you have registered the twitter call back (For Bluemix environment: <application-name>.mybluemix.net/auth/twitter/callback), then you don't need to supply the access token as it is being handled by oath (in https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-nodejs/blob/master/router/auth.js)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  I have registered the callback (though the local environment one: http://server.local:3000/auth/twitter/callback), but it's still throwing me a 500 error.  Any other reason why?

Comment: and have you '(be sure to configure hosts file so server.local points 127.0.0.1)'